# Paragraph structure template generator refactoring

Tags: python, javascript, html

This is an app that generates random statement types, and basic conjunctions. How to improve its readability and function? How to deploy this code app online? This is the GitHub repository: https://github.com/attilavjda/shiny-goggles

```py
#paragraph_builder.py

from flask import Flask, render_template
from random import choice

app = Flask(__name__)

statement_type = ["question", "exclamation", "statement", "implication"]
basic_conjunctions = ["because", "but", "so"]


@app.route("/new")
def new_output():
    return home()


@app.route("/")
def home():
   output = f"""
  Statement type: {choice(statement_type)}
  Basic conjunction: {choice(basic_conjunctions)}
  """
   return render_template("index.html", output=output)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

```html
<!-- /templates/index.html -->

<pre>{{ output }}</pre>
<button onclick="window.location.href='/'">New Term</button>

<script>
  const btn = document.querySelector("button");

  btn.addEventListener("click", () => {
    fetch("/");
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

Vercel has a free tier which you can use to deploy online using their website.

As far as the code goes. It's too small to review.

There are two nitpicks though. As per PEP-8 global constants must be capitalized. So, `statement_type` should be `STATEMENT_TYPE`. It's always good to have a `main()` function to disambiguate scope. But you are not going to use this as a package so it is fine.

Apart from that you are doing all the right things like using multiline text, and using `f-strings` to interpolate strings.

If you have something more substantial then a more informative review can be done.

Answer (score 2):

`statement_type` and `basic_conjunctions` should be immutable tuples and not lists.

Routes for `/` and `/new` can be added to a single function, so do that.

Not a good choice to use a `pre` with fields, nor is it a good idea to perform output formatting in the web control code. Instead, break this out to something more semantically well-structured, like a `dl`.

Your HTML markup is invalid. It needs the typical `html`, etc. tags.

I don't see a need for your `<script>`; delete it and just make the button refresh the current page.

### Suggested

```py
from flask import Flask, render_template
from random import choice

app = Flask(__name__)
statement_type = ('question', 'exclamation', 'statement', 'implication')
basic_conjunctions = ('because', 'but', 'so')


@app.route('/')
@app.route('/new')
def home():
   return render_template(
       'index.html',
       statement_type=choice(statement_type),
       basic_conjunction=choice(basic_conjunctions),
   )


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Paragraph Structure</title>
</head>

<body>

<dl>
  <dt>Statement type:</dt>
  <dd>{{statement_type}}</dd>
  <dt>Basic conjunction:</dt>
  <dd>{{basic_conjunction}}</dd>
</dl>

<button onclick="window.location.reload();">New Term</button>
</body>
</html>
```